# Why are most values True in Boolean?

Tags: python

I found this article about python boolean at [boolean](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_booleans.asp). I was wondering why an empty array, string and the number 0 is false while the other ones are not. Can someone explain this to me? And do note: this is not a duplicate of another article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values in python can be either truthy or falsy.

"", [], 0 are all falsy values.

When there is a value of some kind, it is considered truthy.

They are not the same as true and false but when used as a conditional by themselves they are treated as such.

A lot of programming languages have this concept.

This is just the simple explanation, the answers on this question [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) are far more detailed.

Comment: Though why are empty sets, strings falsy?

Comment: Because they contain no value

Answer (score 0):

This is for easy checking of whether an object has data.

```py
def some_func(some_string: str):
    if some_string:  # both an empty string and None eval to false
        # do something with string
```

If you are wondering why it works, the string and list object have an overloaded `__bool__` special function.

Comment: you can also use an else statement in the code.